# How to measure unknown distribution?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

Assume there are given some unknown distributions.

I know when the data is [normally distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) one can make use of the standard deviation. But what it isn't normally distributed?
[Root mean square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square#Error)? Or is there something different or even "better"?

PS: I aim at comparisons of density curves and/or histograms. Depends on the difficulty to measure/compare.
Background is that I want to compare different pairing methods of 1000 electronic devices. This means, the data pool will be grouped/paired into 500 pairings, each consisting of two devices. The pairings will be measured in their operational parameter distance (via [Mahalanobis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance)):

"*Difference between device1 and device2 (pairing1),
 Difference between device 3 and device 4 (pairing 2),..)*.

I expect that different pairing methods/algorithms result in different pairing distributions and I would like to estimate the best method.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you know about your distributions?

Comment: @StephanKolassa The data represents parameters of >1000 electronic devices. I want to compare different pairing algorithms. I expect that different pairing methods give different distributions of the pairings.

Answer (score 1):

You could

1. Try to transform your density to an approximately normal distribution. Box-Cox might be informative for deciding which transformation is required.
2. Compare both samples with a non parametric technique.

Comment: Thank you! Will have a look at the first. What does the second point mean? I only know non parametric in relation to regression analysis (?).

Comment: Yes there are several non parametric regression techniques, but  there also non parametric equivalents of other tests. E.g. Wilcoxon signed rank and rank sum test are the equivalents of paired sample and two sample t test, respectively.